# Socket.io trigger emit with scroll event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

U can trigger emit like on click event but will it work if it's a gesture / scroll event?

I want to make something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=38&v=tPxjxS198vE

but instead of click I want to use scroll or swipe.

Answer (score 0):

you could call `socket.emit` in scroll event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){
    //you may want to add some conditions first...
    socket.emit('chat message', 'content');
})
```